# In Titanium Appcelerator, is there support for URL based tabGroups?

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, appcelerator

If there is, what is the analogue for Titanium.UI.currentWindow ?

For example to reference a window in a different file, we can use

```
Ti.UI.createWindow({url: 'foo.js'});
```

and in foo.js, point to the current window variable

```
win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
```

Is there a similar method for calling a tab group from a different file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, can you give mord detail?

Answer (score 2):

you can always use `Ti.UI.currentTab` to get the tab you are on, but not the tab group. The easy way to get the tabGroup is to just add it as a property to the window.

```
var tabGroup = Ti.UI.createTabGroup();
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
     url: 'foo.js',
     _tabGroup: tabGroup
});
```

then in you .js file

```
var tabGroup = Ti.UI.currentWindow._tabGroup;
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just do `Ti.UI.currentTabGroup`